# Power set of a countably infinite set using limits.

Tags: limits, elementary-set-theory

I needed to prove that the power set of a countably infinite set is uncountable.

To show that I used the concept of limits to infinity:
$$\mathcal{P}\{|S|\} = \lim_{|S|\to \infty}{2^{|S|}} =  \text{indeterminate form}$$
since, $2^{\infty}$ is an indeterminate form, therefore, we can say that it is uncountable.

Is my "proof" okay? If not, why is it wrong?

Comment: For an actual proof of this, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem.

Comment: I know about the correct proof, I wanted to know what is the mistake if we proceed like that.

Comment: Even if we were talking about limits of real-valued sequences and if the limit were of an indeterminate form, this would not entail that it does not exist.

Comment: "Is my proof okay?" No, you did not write anything resembling a proof.

Comment: What do you know about limits? What is the definition?

Comment: @edm its the value of the function when one of its variable approaches that value(i.e. which is conventionally written below "lim").

Comment: @avDec25 Apparently, you haven't seen a modern definition of limits. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(ε,_δ)-definition_of_limit) for a definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your "proof" is not correct. Indeterminate forms and cardinality of sets have nothing to do with each other. (Also, "$2^\infty$" isn't an indeterminate form . . .)

---

You should re-examine the basic definitions around cardinality, countability, etc. It will be good to start with a slightly easier problem: show that there is no **surjection** from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$. To do this, you need to show how, given an arbitrary function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, you can find a set $X\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ such that $X\not\in im(f)$ (do you see why?). To do this will require a bit of creativity (HINT: if $X$ is a set of natural numbers, and $n\in X\Delta f(n)$, can $X=f(n)$?)

This "easier" problem is actually basically the same as the problem above; but it's made a little more concrete, so it should be easier to see how the answer works.